Bitmap compatibility appears to be broken with the new image host
(Originally posted here, SE image host -- bitmap extension)

Funny, uploading a somewhat less traditional format (Windows Bitmap), direct from file (drag and drop), I obtained this:

Poking around, I find the actual image resides at https://i.sstatic.net/IYK4JzFW.png and it seems the link just wasn't renamed automatically.
Ed: actually, it seems to be worse than that: I see the download is the original 38k file size, and the header is content-type: image/bmp.  The browser doesn't care, so loads it regardless.  So it's not being converted to PNG (as I mostly? expected from the Imgur service?), but is renamed erroneously, ah.

Imgur service ... it is since last week no longer imgur: Stack Exchange’s image hosting arrangement with Imgur is ending - advance notice

@rene Yes, hence past tense.

Ah, fair. I wasn't sure when I parsed that.

The new uploader says: "Supported file types: jpeg, png, gif, or bmp".

I don't see why you'd want to convert it. bmp is a perfectly good format, supporting compressed 24-bit colour. The bug seems to be an accidental rename, which I'm guessing is a copy-paste issue somewhere.

I mean I don't mind if a host were to convert it to an objectively better format (PNG, I think, supports everything and more that common BMP formats used? plus the compression is better, and obligatory). But that's a storage and bandwidth optimization.  As a user, it doesn't matter to me, all I want is a pixel-exact (or high quality lossy-compressed, if too many colors) image out the other side.

This is not the expected behavior. A fix for bmp images is coming. In the meantime your workaround by changing to png works.

This should be fixed now. Like Imgur, any bmp file is converted to a png during the upload process. You should no longer need to change the extension on the image after it's uploaded.

Congrats for your first post in Stack Exchange! That's what I call starting with style. :D

Thanks! I've been here for over a year, but not posted anything. I should merge my personal account with my work account since I've been a user for over 10 years.

Cheers, that would be nice indeed. While at it, any chance to take a look on the issue mentioned in this chat message, where chat bot that used to upload to SE can't upload now due to more strict size limit? Thanks!

Hard to tell from that link. Are you referring to the height/width of an image, or the file size?

File size, but the bot owner already handled it by now, so guess all is good. Thanks!
